# Why do the full and lite version of Raspbian have a different kernel version?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-lite

I have built some software to run on Raspbian, and did so on the full image of Raspbian. Now I wish to switch to Raspbian Lite for my release, as I no longer need all the gui packages.
After doing this, I have found that my software behaves significantly differently. Checking uname, I see that the full and lite images on raspberrypi.org have different kernel versions, yet are both dated 2017-04-10.

Lite:

```
$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.4.50-v7+ #970 SMP Mon Feb 20 19:18:29 GMT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/rpi-issue
Raspberry Pi reference 2017-04-10
Generated using pi-gen, https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen, acc4f56597e75225b93be3e1e20504a40565a9b9, stage2
```

Full:

```
$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.24-v7+ #993 SMP Wed Apr 26 18:01:23 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/rpi-issue
Raspberry Pi reference 2017-04-10
Generated using pi-gen, https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen, acc4f56597e75225b93be3e1e20504a40565a9b9, stage5
```

My understanding was that the Lite version was supposed to be the same, with just a minimal set of packages, however this is not what I'm witnessing.
Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK **BOTH** have the latest official kernel viz. `4.4.50`. Performing an `upgrade` updates the kernel to `4.9.24` which was not released before 2017-04-10. NOTE `rpi-issue` is not particularly helpful, mine says "Raspberry Pi reference 2015-09-24 (armhf)"

Comment: Thanks @Milliways. After reading @user68856's response, I performed an `apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel` and it came up to that version. What is the 'upgrade' you are referring to, if different to `apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel`?

Comment: You should do `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel` to the latest supported kernel/bootcode, but `apt get upgrade` should do this automatically.